# The identifier is not in the scope [Unity, VS2019]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I've recently switched to the `Visual Studio 2019` (previously 2017) along with `Unity 2019.1.3f1` (previously ~2019.1.0 something), with new `Tools for Unity` in Visual Studio and I have stumbled upon a problem.

When I am debugging, I can't see the variable from my Singleton class (e.g., GameManager.Instance.Var, Instance is `public static`). If I try to see it through Immediate Window it gives me this:

`The identifier 'GameManager' is not in the scope`

Hovering over any part of it (GameManager, Instance, Var) doesn't give any info at all, CodeLens is not working with it.

It sucks, because now I can't debug properly, only `Debug.Log` lol...

Help! What can I do? It seems that I can't find any similiar issues.

Here's a pic of my settings for `Tools for Unity`:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, I figured it out, it was a Visual Studio 2019 bug, I've reported it to the Microsoft, they are going to fix it.
Here's the link to the problem:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/581763/unity-development-in-visual-studio-2019.html

Comment: It's also worth mentioning, from the thread you linked, that fully declaring the namespace of the object is a workaround for now. I've justed tested that, and it allows me to view the singleton in the debugger, where without the namespace all I got was the "not in the scope" message.